# unwrap second level array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the fallowing multidimensional array structure:

```
array
  '2012-10-02' => 
     array
       0 => 
        array
          'item1' => 
            array
              ...

   '2012-10-03' => 
     array
       0 => 
         array
           'item1' => 
             array
               ...
```

How do I unwrap Item arrays so that structure would be like this:

```
array
  '2012-10-02' => 
     array
       'item1' => 
          array
           ...
   '2012-10-03' => 
      array
        'item1' => 
          array
            ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array and for each item "promote" `$item[0]` to the place that `$item` used to have. So for example:

```
foreach($input as &$element) {  // by reference!
    $element = $element[0];
}

// not strictly required, but prevents you from accidentally messing with
// $element outside of the loop (which would almost certainly be a bug)
unset($element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `array_map` to return the first element

```
$array = array("2012-10-02" => array(array("item1"=>array())),"2012-10-03" => array(array("item1"=>array())));

#before
var_dump($array);

$array = array_map(function($var) {return $var[0];} , $array);

#after
var_dump($array);
```

before

```
array
  '2012-10-02' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'item1' => 
            array
              ...
  '2012-10-03' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'item1' => 
            array
              ...
```

After

```
array
  '2012-10-02' => 
    array
      'item1' => 
        array
          empty
  '2012-10-03' => 
    array
      'item1' => 
        array
          empty
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP PDO `fetchAll` with `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` results in a similar situation when grouped by unique keys. Using the results as-is requires data access such as `$rows['key_1'][0]['data_1']`. The loop below gets rid of the extraneous wrapper array. Then the same data can be accessed as `$rows['key_1']['data_1']`.

```
public function get_unique_assoc_rows() {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT assoc_key, other_field'
            . ' FROM some_table');
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        $row = $row[0];
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Note: For non-unique keys, don't do this, as you'll need the wrapper array.